# HOw do i use this local variable

Tags: javascript

When I run first.js I get undefined.
I think the mistake is super small but how do i fix this so "entered" will print  false and not undefined

main.js:

```
var enter = false;
module.exports = onProximityBoolean(enter);
function onProximityBoolean(enter) {
    if (enter === true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

first.js:

```
var main =('main.js').onProximityBoolean;
console.log(main);
```

Comment: try moving module.exports = onProximityBoolean(enter); below the function.  Depending on how your javascript is loaded and ran, you might be trying to run the function before it exists

Comment: i tried that and it didnt work, i am still getting undefined

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Based on your code sample `enter` is always false. Are you trying to export the `onProximityBoolean` function?

Comment: im trying to print enter,whatever that may be(it is false here) and if that involves exporting the onProximityBoolean function then yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var enter = false;
function onProximityBoolean(enter) {
    if (enter === true) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
module.exports = onProximityBoolean(enter);
```

and then use it like this:

```
var main = require('./main.js');
console.log(main);
```

If you wanted to use it as `var main =('main.js').onProximityBoolean` you'd need to change the definition of your `exports` to this:

```
module.exports.onProximityBoolean = onProximityBoolean(enter);
```

Comment: hi this didnt work, in fact when i run either of those it says "main() is not a function" or "('main.js').onProximityBoolean(); is not a function" respectively

Comment: sorry the edits you made still give me "main() is not a function"

Comment: yeah, edited again, sorry, I didn't get what you wanted to do before. Worked  with node for me like this

Comment: @LisnaVargheese you're welcome! Though I have to mention, that this code is way to long for what it does, especially the `onProximityBoolean` function

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually require `main.js` in your code. Instead of `var main =('main.js').onProximityBoolean;`, use `var main = require('main.js');`. Then `console.log(main)` will return false (the value exported from `main.js`).

If you're using this in the browser, you'll have to do something with Browserify or Webpack to build a bundle that includes your required files. If you're just using Node, it will work as is.

**EDIT**

In the `onProximityBoolean` function, it's not necessary to check `enter === true`. You could actually change that function to just return `true` or `false` based on the argument passed in:

```
function onProximityBoolean(enter) {
    return enter; // if enter is always `true` or `false`
}
```

Comment: To be honest it could just be narrowed down to `modules.export = enter` or even `modules.export = false` heh